# timestamp before an echo

Tags: shell, timestamps, echo

Is there a nicer way to create a timestamp in front of an `echo`?

Currently I do it this way:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if mount | grep -q /mnt/usb; then
        echo `date +%R\ ` "usb device already mounted"
else
        echo `date +%R\ ` "mounting usb device..."
        mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0s1 /mnt/usb

        if mount | grep -q /mnt/usb; then
                echo `date +%R\ ` "usb device successfully mounted"
        fi
fi
```

The output should look something like this:

```
10:36 usb device already mounted
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could skip the `echo`, and just put the message in the `date` command. `date` allows you to insert text into the format string (`+%R` in your example). For example:

```
date +"%R usb device already mounted"
```

You can also throw it into a shell function for convenience. For example:

```
echo_time() {
    date +"%R $*"
}

echo_time "usb device already mounted"
```

This is a cleaner if you are going to re-use it many times.

Comment: `echo_time` will do what you expect, until your message has a `%` sign in it. Not a very robust solution.

Comment: @derobert Because the implementation is hidden away in a function, `echo_time` could just use the OP's date+echo construct

Comment: i'd just change "$*" by "$@" (to get in the habit of using the later)

Comment: how to use that in a pipe?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more robust and portable (POSIX) way to do it, particularly one that allows for `%` to stay unprocessed as an argument:

```
echo_time() {
    date +"%H:%M $(printf "%s " "$@" | sed 's/%/%%/g')"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a variable for `date +%R`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

T=$(date +%R)

if mount | grep -q /mnt/usb; then
        echo "$T usb device already mounted"
else
        echo "$T mounting usb device..."
        mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0s1 /mnt/usb

        if mount | grep -q /mnt/usb; then
                echo "$T usb device successfully mounted"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: This is nice because it only calls date once, rather than three times.

Comment: This is nice when the script does not last long, but it will have the wrong date when it will be longer.

Answer (score 4):

With `ksh93` and recent versions of `bash`:

```
ts_echo() {
  printf '%(%R)T: %s\n' -1 "$*"
}
```

With  `zsh`:

```
ts_echo() print -P %T: "$@"
```

Or to avoid prompt expansion in the `"$@"` part:

```
ts_echo() echo ${(%):-%T}: "$@"
```

A hacky way for older versions of `bash`:

```
ts_echo() (
  PS4="\A"
  set -x; : "$@"
)
```

Actually, if the point is to do:

```
echo "<timestamp>: doing cmd args..."
cmd args...
```

You could do:

```
ts() (
  PS4='\A: doing '
  set -x; "$@"
)
ts cmd args...
```

Or to avoid forking a sub shell:

```
ts() {
  local PS4='\A: doing ' ret
  set -x; "$@"
  { ret=$?; set +x; } 2> /dev/null
  return "$ret"
}
```

Then:

```
$ ts echo whatever
14:32: doing echo whatever
whatever
```

(note that those are echoed on stderr, which actually may be preferable).

Answer (score 1):

When I do things like this, I usually want all lines (including any program output) to be timestamped. Thus, I'd use something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

(
    if mount | grep -q /mnt/usb; then
        echo "usb device already mounted"
    else
        echo "mounting usb device..."
        mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0s1 /mnt/usb

        if mount | grep -q /mnt/usb; then
            echo "usb device successfully mounted"
        fi
    fi
) 2>&1 | perl -ne 'print "[".localtime()."] $_"'
```

As Stephane points out below, individual programs may buffer their output when sent to a pipe. Of course, these buffers will be flushed when the program exits so at worst the timestamps will show when the program exited (if it buffers its output and does not print enough to fill the buffer). However, the `echo` timestamps will all be accurate.

As a runnable sample for testing:

```
#!/bin/sh

(
    echo "Doing something"
    sleep 5
    echo "Doing something else..."
    ls /some/file
    sleep 8
    echo "Done."
) 2>&1 | perl -ne 'print "[".localtime()."] $_"'
```

Output:

```
[Thu Aug 29 07:32:37 2013] Doing something
[Thu Aug 29 07:32:42 2013] Doing something else...
[Thu Aug 29 07:32:42 2013] ls: cannot access /some/file: No such file or directory
[Thu Aug 29 07:32:50 2013] Done.
```

Comment: However note that once the output is going to a pipe, applications start to buffer their output, so the timings may not reflect the time they were printed.

Comment: I suggest checking out the `ts` command which is part of moreutils. Its a similar perl script, but with various options for timestamp format, etc.

Comment: @derobert - why don't you write up how to do this using `ts`? Seems like it would be the best option here.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating timestamps with `ts`**

install the tool `ts` (part of package `moreutils)`:

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

Adding a timestamp to an output:

```
echo "foo" | ts
```

output:

```
Sep 03 14:51:44 foo
```

Answer (score -1):

```
alias echo="d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d); echo $d "
echo hola
```

Comment: This didn't work when I just tried it.

Comment: Just as @slm wrote. You have to protect the string from premature command and variable expansions.